# Install & run an extra APK file with Kivy

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

I am currently developing mobile applications in Kivy. I would like to create an app to aid in the development process. This app would download an APK file from a network location and install/run it. I know how to download files of course. How can I programmatically install and run an Android APK file in Kivy/Android/Python3?

Answer (score 0):

Look up how you would do it in Java, then you should be able to do it from Kivy using Pyjnius.